# How to update get_stylesheet_directory_uri in wordpresss

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How do I update get_stylesheet_directory_uri? Transferring a website and I have already updated the url for the site inside wp-config using:

define('WP_HOME','https://somewebsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://somewebsite.com');

Still when get_stylesheet_directory_uri is called it is using a previous url, any idea on how to force this to update?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Once you change the site URL using those DEFINE statements, you also need to flush the permalink settings. Just go to wp-admin -> Settings -> Permalinks, and save without making any changes. That should force it to use your new values.

Comment: It is not working for me, still coming from the old URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the site via FTP, then this method will help you quickly get a site back up and running, if you changed those values incorrectly.

1. FTP to the site, and get a copy of the active theme's functions.php file. You're going to edit it in a simple text editor and upload it back to the site.
2. Add these two lines to the file.

update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );

Use your own URL instead of example.com, obviously.

3. Upload the file back to your site, in the same location. FileZilla offers a handy "edit file" function to do all of the above rapidly; if you can use that, do so.
4. Load the login or admin page a couple of times. The site should come back up.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can happen if your site is multilingual is that `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` is used in a registered string whose translation is still using the previous domain. In that case, search and replace your translations with the new domain.